# What is wrong with this ListAdapter edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I think i'm doing something very basic wrong here. I'm not able to edit any of my editText fields that are being generated by my list adaptor (the text boxes are showing, i'm able to put the cursor on the field but i'm not able to type/delete any text).  Here's my code.

**My ListAdaptor**
    public class LoanRepaymentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final List<CurrentRepaymentInstallment> loansForRepayment;
private final Activity context;

public LoanRepaymentListAdapter(Activity context, List<CurrentRepaymentInstallment> loansForRepayment) {
    super(context, R.layout.loan_repayments, loansForRepayment);
    this.context = context;
    this.loansForRepayment = loansForRepayment;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView borrowerName;
    protected TextView loanAmount;
    protected TextView installmentNumber;
    protected TextView estimatedTotal;
    protected EditText repaymentAmount;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.loan_repayments, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.borrowerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.borrowerName);
        viewHolder.loanAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.loanAmount);
        viewHolder.installmentNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.installmentNumber);
        viewHolder.estimatedTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.estimatedTotal);
        viewHolder.repaymentAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.repaymentAmount);
        viewHolder.repaymentAmount.setEditableFactory(Editable.Factory.getInstance());
        viewHolder.repaymentAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                String repaymentAmount = arg0.toString();
                loansForRepayment.get(position).setRepaymentAmount(Float.parseFloat(repaymentAmount));
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.repaymentAmount.setTag(loansForRepayment.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).repaymentAmount.setTag(loansForRepayment.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.borrowerName.setText(loansForRepayment.get(position).getLoanProfileBasicInfo().getBorrowerBasicInfo().getFirstName());
    holder.loanAmount.setText("Rs. " + Float.toString(loansForRepayment.get(position).getLoanProfileBasicInfo().getLoanAmountInPaisa()/100));
    holder.estimatedTotal.setText("Rs. " + Float.toString(loansForRepayment.get(position).getEstimatedTotalAmount()/100));
    holder.installmentNumber.setText("Inst no - " + Integer.toString(loansForRepayment.get(position).getInstallmentNumber()));
    float repaymentAmt = loansForRepayment.get(position).getRepaymentAmount();
    if(repaymentAmt != 0.0) holder.repaymentAmount.setText(Float.toString(repaymentAmt));
    return view;
}
}
```

**My XML loan_repayments**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/screenTitle" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+layout/loan_disbursement_footer"
     />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/borrowerName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loanAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/installmentNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/estimatedTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/repaymentAmount"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="12sp"
     >
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Activity Code**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    lastKnownLocation = Utility.getLastKnownLocation(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    loansForRepayment = (ArrayList<CurrentRepaymentInstallment>)intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.CURRENT_REPAYMENT_INSTALLMENT);
    ArrayAdapter<CurrentRepaymentInstallment> adapter = new LoanRepaymentListAdapter(this, loansForRepayment);

    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loan_disbursement_footer, null);
    getListView().addFooterView(footer);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disburse);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Also would like to know how I can set the value of the edited text in my list onChange. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use `EditText` instead of `TextView`?

UPDATE: looks like I misunderstood at the first pass. You probably mean `repaymentAmount` is not editable. Right? If yes, then try to comment out the following lines:

```
viewHolder.repaymentAmount.addTextChangedListener( ...
viewHolder.repaymentAmount.setEditableFactory( ...
```

Will it still remain non-editable?

Comment: it was not a code issue. The problem was that when i selected the editText, the keyboard popped up on my emulator and deselected the editText. is this because I'm doing it on the emulator or is there a way to tightly control this?

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan: sorry I can not tell what the reason is, you need to try it on a real device.

Comment: will try it out on a real device and get back.

Comment: I tried it it out on a real device and it is exhibiting the same behaviour. any idea what i should do to fix this?

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan: sorry the issue is tricky, I don't understand why it behaves this way... :(

Comment: I have the same issue resolve it using set this property in manifest activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". but it has an issue its fix my view which is not completely scrollable when soft keyboard open. is there any guidance about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just enable your edittext through property and set Listener on it, when you enter text in edittext after completing(or use onfocusChangedListener as i think) it will reflect changes to required textview.once you completed typing inside Editext.